# Regex for retrieving the parameter of the CSS url function

Tags: c#, css, regex, parsing

I'm trying to get the url portion of the following string:

```
url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png)
```

So the required part if `images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png`.

Currently I've got this:

```
url\((?<url>.*)\)
```

But it seems to be choking on the following example:

```
url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .30;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30)
```

Which results in `images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .30;filter:Alpha(Opacity=30`...

I'd like to make sure that it supports as many variations as possible (additional whitespace etc).

Thanks!
Kieron

#### Edit

Additionally, I need to ignore the optional quotes ' or " ...

Now, it looks like this:

```
url\(['|"]?(?<url>[^)]+)\)
```

I can't seem to get it to stop/ ignore the last quote...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the greediness of the * quantifier, try a negated character class instead of a .

```
url\((?<url>[^)]*)\)
```

or you could use the lazy operator

```
url\((?<url>.*?)\)
```

First choice is proabably better.

Edit: To ignore the second quote, you will want to use the lazy quantifier like this

```
url\(['"]?(?<url>[^)]+?)['"]?\)
```

You don't use the alternation meta character `|` within a character class.

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, reg-ex is one of those things that I have to re-learn every time I use it - even if it's been 10mins since I last did any. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Kieron: once you decide to solve trouble with regex - you have 2 troubles ;-)

Comment: Updated, Regex is great really, just so often abused and misunderstood!

Comment: >> To ignore the second quote --- just put another char to excluding set [^\\)']

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.*` with `[^\)]+`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
url\(['"]?(?<url>.*?)['"]?\)
```

But you might want to allow for optional whitespace:

```
url\s*\(['"\s]*(?<url>.*?)['"\s]*\)
```

That will also match some invalid strings, but that shouldn't be a problem if your CSS is valid.

On more thing: that `|` in `['|"]` does not act as an OR operator, it just matches a literal `|`.  OR is implicit in character classes.

Answer (score 0):

<del>url\((.*\.png)</del>

```
url\\((.[^)]*)\\)
```